# How to run PostgreSQL after install on a clean Ubuntu build?

Tags: postgresql, conda

I've just installed Ubuntu, installed Conda, several packages including Django and PostgreSQL via Conda (with Conda installed PostgreSQL). That's it, nothing else.

I'm trying to follow the instructions here: https://github.com/rdkit/OCEAN. Rather than creating a virtual environment I've created a Conda one instead. I'm not sure if that's going to make any difference.

Also please note: this is a clean build. I have not activated anything or created any DB user etc. All I've done is activate the Conda env of choice and started installing the packages listed on the link above.

I'm having problems with the initial PostgreSQL instructions recreated here...

Get a clone of OCEAN from the Repo:

```
git clone https://www.github.com/rdkit/OCEAN.git
cd OCEAN

Create a PostgreSQL-User, the database for OCEAN and fill the OCEAN-DB:

# create PostgreSQL-User for OCEAN
# password 'ocean_pw' should be used when asked,
# according to database-entry in settings.py
createuser -P -s -d -r -e ocean_user

# create PostgreSQL-Database for OCEAN
createdb --owner=ocean_user ocean
```

When I try `createuser -P -s -d -r -e ocean_user` and then add the required password (in the Git link) I get the error:

> createuser: error: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory. Is the server running locally or accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

I have a Conda environment and on a very clean Ubuntu machine. The last time I touched a DB was years ago. How can I resolve this?

Comment: You are probably best off referring to whatever docs this "conda" thing has about how it sets up PostgreSQL's config files and how to get it to start up. Typically the server process would run under the "postgres" system user and you would be able to connect as db-user "postgres" from that system account locally without a password. That is how you would create your first user etc.

Comment: You probably have no running PostgreSQL server. Read the documentation how to create a cluster with `initdb` (or, on Ubuntu, `pg_createcluster`) and how to start the server.

Comment: See here [Ubuntu Postgres](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/databases-postgresql) for information on how to manage Postgres on Ubuntu.